# Python regex to capture Cisco Switch ports

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a script to grab some information from switches in my network. The script takes a list of ports as input and finds corresponding information.

I am using Python 3.5.2

**User Input:**
Gi1/0/1,Gi0/1,Fa2/3,FastEthernet4/5,Giga1/0/2

**Expected Output:**
['Gi1/0/1','Gi0/1','Fa2/3','FastEthernet4/5','Giga1/0/2']

I have tried:

```py
   capture_three_ports = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+")
   capture_two_ports = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
   array_ports_three = re.findall(capture_three_ports,raw_ports)
   array_ports_two = re.findall(capture_two_ports,raw_ports)
```

It doesn't work because *capture_two_ports* captures partial *capture_three_ports*

Comment: Why not just split on the comma? `ports = inp.split(',')`

Comment: Because I am dumb. Haha sorry. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it's hard to see the forest from the trees as they say :).